# Fly-out menu with images

Tags: menu, custom-menu

How can I create a drop down fly-out menu with images? Similar to the Microsoft's menu. Screenshot and link to Microsoft's example.

[image]

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx

Thank you